# if rank$(T)$=rank$(T^2)$, then $V=R(T)+N(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$
The statement above isn't exactly what the problem says; rather, I'm asked to show if $\rank(T)=\rank(T^2)$ then $V=R(T)+N(T)$ (where $R$ is the range and $N$ is the kernel), and $R(T)\cap N(T)=0$.

I've shown we must have $R(T)=R(T^2)$, and that $R(T)\cap N(T)=0$. I'm stuck on 
showing $V=R(T)+N(T)$. I'm trying to show it as such:

Let $v\in V$. Then write $v=T(v)+(v-T(v))$. The first is in $R(T)$, so I need to show $v-T(v)\in N(T)$, so that
$$T(v-T(v))=T(v)-T^2(v)=T(v)-T(v)=0$$

But clearly I need $T^2=T$ for this to work. I'm really struggling to show this, any hints/suggestions? Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.

Edit: I changed the question because my assumption was wrong. So now I'm even more lost on how to show $V=R(T)+N(T)$.

Comment: What you propose is not true. Take $T=$ rotation of 90º degrees for instance. $T$ and $T^2$ have the same rank, but are different.

Comment: If you have shown $R\cap N=\{0\}$  the rest follows from the [Rank-Nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: @AG That's fantastic and I'm not sure how I missed it. Thank you!

Comment: @quid I'm sorry, but I don't understand your request. I did not attempt to provide a proof of the proposition he mentioned, I just showed him that what he asked for (namely, that if it was true that $R(T)=R(T^2)$ implied $T=T^2$) was false.

Comment: @quid I read the question more closely: the OP wants to prove a false statement in order to prove a true one. The comment by Aloizio Macedo is very good indeed.

Comment: I don't understand how this follows from rank nullity theorem. the rank nullity theorem deals with dimensions, while the question deals with equality of vector spaces.

Comment: @OriaGruber Yep I realized this when I went to try and write it down. So nope I'm still stuck

Comment: @egreg Yeah he's right my assumption was wrong. Shame on me for not being able to cook up such an easy counterexample

Comment: @egreg it depends what one thinks  is referred to. I took the main question and thus the default target of a reference to be the *actual claim that needs to be shown.* Not some auxiliary result the OP thinks might be useful.  But I grant one can also see this differently.

Comment: @mathers101 If you really have shown that $R(T)\cap N(T)=0$, you have $\dim(R(T)+N(T))=\dim R(T)+\dim N(T)$. What does rank-nullity say?

Comment: @egreg That is equal to $Dim(V)$. But that does not mean that $R(T)+N(T) = V$. Not all $n$ dimensional spaces are the same (although they are isomorphic).

Comment: @OriaGruber But $R(T)+N(T)\subseteq V$ so the fact that the dimensions are the same gives equality. Thanks egreg

Comment: Why is it that $R(T)+N(T) \subseteq V$? Come to think of it, not once in this thread was $V$ defined.

Comment: @OriaGruber $T$ is an endomorphism of a finite dimensional vector space $V$; it should be said at the beginning, but it can be inferred.

Comment: @egreg This is correct, I thought it was obvious enough

Comment: Obvious is the most dangerous word in mathematics :)

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I took the question differently. But regardless my comment was phrase in a bad way. Sorry about that. I deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume from context that $T$ is a linear transformation (since we're talking about rank and kernel), and that $T:V\to V$ (since otherwise $T^2$ wouldn't make sense).

I further assume that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space. This turns out to be *crucial*, as the result need not hold without it.

For example, consider $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N},$ the set of sequences $\vec x=\langle x_n\rangle_{n\in\Bbb N},$ where $\Bbb N$ is the set of positive integers and $x_n\in\Bbb R$ for all $n\in\Bbb N.$ We can define addition and scalar multiplication in a natural way as $$\vec x+\vec y=\langle x_n+y_n\rangle_{n\in\Bbb N}$$ and $$c\vec x=\langle cx_n\rangle_{n\in\Bbb N}$$ to make $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ a vector space over $\Bbb R.$

For any $k\in\Bbb N,$ we let $\vec e^{(k)}$ be the vector having $1$ as its $k$th entry and $0$ for all other entries. Readily, the vectors $\vec e^{(k)}$ comprise a basis for $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ over $\Bbb R.$

Now, consider the linear transformation $T:V\to V$ given by $\vec e^{(1)}\mapsto\vec 0$ and $\vec e^{(k)}\mapsto\vec e^{(k-1)}$ for all other $k\in\Bbb N.$ What does this look like in general, though? Well, with a bit of work, we can show that $$\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots\rangle\mapsto\langle x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,\dots\rangle.$$

Thus, $R(T)=R(T^2)=\Bbb R^{\Bbb N},$ and $N(T)$ is the subspace generated by $\vec e^{(1)}.$

On the other hand, if we assume that $V$ is finite-dimensional, then by showing  $R(T)\cap N(T)=0,$ we have $$\dim(R(T)+N(T))=\dim V-\dim R(T)\cap N(T)=\dim V$$ by rank-nullity. Thus, since $V$ is finite-dimensional and $R(T)+N(T)\subseteq V,$ then....